# GUI freeze with selenium and Python browser dependent

Tags: python, user-interface, python-multithreading, freeze

I am very new to Selenium, Python. I have developed a automation tool which collects login details from the user and feed it to the site and then proceed with the details GUI, collect details again and login to different web browsers to fetch the data and proceed to create an template. Since most of the tasks are browser dependent, the GUI always shows not responding.

Heard about Multithreading but not sure how to arrange already written code into it. Can someone help?

Comment: it is unlikely that you would need multiprocessing. but in any event, what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example